# How to occupy a HID device exclusively from even Window manager in Window system

Tags: windows, hid, directinput, gamepad

Sorry, I am a newbie in window technical.
I am fine in reading input data from device by RawInput or DirectInput now.
But, I concern about:
I want a service (be called X ) can read data from Gamepad(Both ForeGround and BackGround state). Can X disconnect associate between Window manager and Gamepad ? Thanks